# Как сделать что бы исчезли 2 совпавшие карты?

Tags: javascript

```js
class AudioController {
    constructor() {
        this.bgMusic = new Audio('Assets/Audio/start.mp3');
        this.flipSound = new Audio('Assets/Audio/flip.wav');
        this.matchSound = new Audio('Assets/Audio/match.wav');
        this.victorySound = new Audio('Assets/Audio/winner.mp3');
        this.gameOverSound = new Audio('Assets/Audio/end.mp3');
        this.bgMusic.volume = 0.2; /* звук */
        this.bgMusic.loop = true; /* повтор музыки */
    }
    startMusic() {
        this.bgMusic.play();
    }
    stopMusic() {
        this.bgMusic.pause();
        this.bgMusic.currentTime = 0;
    }
    flip() {
        this.flipSound.play();
    }
    match() {
        this.matchSound.play();
    }
    victory() {
        this.stopMusic();
        this.victorySound.play();
    }
    gameOver() {
        this.stopMusic();
        this.gameOverSound.play();
    }
}

class MixOrMatch {
    constructor(totalTime, cards) {
        this.cardsArray = cards;
        this.totalTime = totalTime;
        this.timeRemaining = totalTime;
        this.timer = document.getElementById('time-remaining') /* отсчёт времени */
        this.ticker = document.getElementById('flips') /* flips клик по карте! */
        this.audioController = new AudioController();
    }

    startGame() {
        this.totalClicks = 0;
        this.timeRemaining = this.totalTime;
        this.cardToCheck = null;
        this.matchedCards = [];
        this.busy = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.audioController.startMusic();
            this.shuffleCards(this.cardsArray); /* перемешать карты */
            this.countdown = this.startCountdown();
            this.busy = false;
        }, 400)
        this.hideCards();
        this.timer.innerText = this.timeRemaining;
        this.ticker.innerText = this.totalClicks;
    }
    startCountdown() {
        return setInterval(() => {
            this.timeRemaining--;
            this.timer.innerText = this.timeRemaining;
            if (this.timeRemaining === 0)
                this.gameOver();
        }, 1000);
    }
    gameOver() {
        clearInterval(this.countdown);
        this.audioController.gameOver();
        document.getElementById('game-over-text').classList.add('visible');
    }
    victory() {
        clearInterval(this.countdown);
        this.audioController.victory();
        document.getElementById('victory-text').classList.add('visible');
    }
    hideCards() {
        this.cardsArray.forEach(card => {
            card.classList.remove('visible');
            card.classList.remove('matched');
        });
    }
    flipCard(card) {
        if (this.canFlipCard(card)) {
            this.audioController.flip();
            this.totalClicks++;
            this.ticker.innerText = this.totalClicks; /* сколько flips */
            card.classList.add('visible'); /* Анимация */

            if (this.cardToCheck) {
                this.checkForCardMatch(card);
            } else {
                this.cardToCheck = card;
            }
        }
    }
    checkForCardMatch(card) { /* проверка совподения карт */

        if (this.getCardType(card) === this.getCardType(this.cardToCheck))
            this.cardMatch(card, this.cardToCheck);
        else
            this.cardMismatch(card, this.cardToCheck);

        this.cardToCheck = null;
    }
    cardMatch(card1, card2) {
        this.matchedCards.push(card1);
        this.matchedCards.push(card2);
        card1.classList.add('matched');
        card2.classList.add('matched');
        this.audioController.match();
        if (this.matchedCards.length === this.cardsArray.length)
            this.victory();
    }
    cardMismatch(card1, card2) {
        this.busy = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            card1.classList.remove('visible');
            card2.classList.remove('visible');
            this.busy = false;
        }, 1000);
    }
    shuffleCards(cardsArray) {
        for (let i = cardsArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            cardsArray[randIndex].style.order = i;
            cardsArray[i].style.order = randIndex;
        }
    }
    getCardType(card) {
        return card.getElementsByClassName('card-value')[0].src;
    }
    canFlipCard(card) {
        return !this.busy && !this.matchedCards.includes(card) && card !== this.cardToCheck;
    }
}

if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
} else {
    ready();
}

function ready() {
    let overlays = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-text'));
    let cards = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('card'));
    let game = new MixOrMatch(220, cards); /* time Start game 220*/

    overlays.forEach(overlay => {
        overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
            overlay.classList.remove('visible');
            game.startGame();
        });
    });

    cards.forEach(card => {
        card.addEventListener('click', () => {
            game.flipCard(card);
        });
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    min-height: 100vh;
    cursor: url(Assets/Cursors/Ghost.cur), auto;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(Assets/baground/hearthstone-legend-warcraft-heroes-hd-wallpapers-2_xtn2.jpg)
    /* background: radial-gradient(#9D5900, #3D2200); */
}

.page-title {
    color: #fff59d;
    /* font-weight: normal; */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.game-info-container {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.game-info {
    color: #fff59d;
    font-size: 4em;
}

.game-container {
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    perspective: 500px;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    cursor: url("Assets/Cursors/GhostHover.cur"), auto;
    height: 175px;
    width: 125px;
}

.card-face {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card.visible .card-back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card.visible .card-front {
    transform: rotateY(0);
}

.card-back {
    background-color: black;
    border-color: #fff59d;
    transform: rotateY(0);
}

.cob-web {
    position: absolute;
    transition: width 100ms ease-in-out, height 100ms ease-in-out;
    width: 47px;
    height: 47px;
}

.card-face:hover .cob-web {
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
}

.cob-web-top-left {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.cob-web-top-right {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.cob-web-bottom-left {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.cob-web-bottom-right {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.spider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-self: flex-start;
    transition: transform 100ms ease-in-out;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.card-back:hover .spider {
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.card-value {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.card-front {
    background-color: #FFBB89;
    border-color: #333;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.overlay-text {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #fff59d;
    font-family: Creepy, serif;
    transition: background-color 500ms, font-size 500ms;
}

.overlay-text-small {
    font-size: .3em;
}

.overlay-text.visible {
    display: flex;
    animation: overlay-grow 500ms forwards;
}

@keyframes overlay-grow {
    from {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        font-size: 0;
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
        font-size: 10em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .game-container {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto)
    }
    .game-info-container {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js" async></script>
    <title>Game</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="page-title">Gnome Tavern</h1>
    <div class="overlay-text visible">
        Click to Start
    </div>
    <div id="game-over-text" class="overlay-text">
        GAME OVER
        <span class="overlay-text-small">Click to Restart</span>
    </div>
    <div id="victory-text" class="overlay-text">
        VICTORY
        <span class="overlay-text-small">Click to Restart</span>
    </div>

    <div class="game-container">
        <div class="game-info-container">
            <div class="game-info">
                Time <span id="time-remaining">250</span>
            </div>
            <div class="game-info">
                Flips <span id="flips">0</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/4.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/4.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">
                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/5.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/5.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/6.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/6.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/7.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/7.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/8.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/8.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/9.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/9.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/10.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/10.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/11.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/11.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/12.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/12.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/13.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/13.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/14.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/14.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/15.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/15.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/16.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-back card-face">

                <img class="spider" src="Assets/Images/face.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-front card-face">

                <img class="card-value" src="Assets/Images/16.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно не обрабатывать клик по совпавшим картам (или в обработчике делать проверку на то, что карты уже вышли из игры). Скрыть же совпавшие карты можно, установив css-свойство [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/visibility). В принципе, можно обойтись одним только css, используя ещё и свойство [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).